# Use the generate_files_directory method to change the FielField upload_to param do not work

Tags: python, django, filefield

I write a generate_files_directory method to generate the upload path:

```
def generate_files_directory(self,filepath):
    url = "images/%s" % (filepath)
    return url
```

The model is bellow:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="imgs/test/")
    pic = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_files_directory)
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
```

The form code is bellow:

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('pic', 'filepath')
```

my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img.is_valid():
            img.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

and I write a home.html to upload the files:

```
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>picture</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    {% for img in images %}
        {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
        ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But seem it did not upload to the generated path, it still upload to the `/images/` directory:

[image]

all in there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: did you check the filepath ? did you get your desired value ?Are you sure  it is not empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generate_files_directory` method is wrong, it should be:

```
def generate_files_directory(instance, filename):
    url = "images/%s" % instance.filepath # will output something like `images/imgs/test/`
    return url
```

As stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#filefield) in the Django documentation, the `upload_to` method will be given two arguments:

> **instance**
> An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. More specifically, this is the particular instance where the current file is being attached.
>
> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field.
>
> **filename**
> The filename that was originally given to the file. This may or may not be taken into account when determining the final destination path.